# Does django accept Jinja loop together with condintion in one line?

Tags: django, django-templates, jinja2

There's a wonderful example in Jinja [docs](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/) regarding how not to use `break`:

```
{% for user in users if not user.hidden %}
    <li>{{ user.username|e }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

However when trying to use similar approach in Django template it gives me error:

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /childminder/task-list/

'for' statements should use the format 'for x in y': for link in form.links if link.status == form.status
```

Original code:

```
 {% for link in form.links if link.status == form.status %} 
      {% url link.url id=application_id %}
 {% else %}
      {% for link in form.links if link.status == "Other" %}
          {% url link.url id=application_id %}
      {% endfor %}
 {% endfor %}
```

Point is that I list of links in a list of forms (so those links belongs to specific form only), and there's `status` and `url` in that list of links. IF all link statuses didn't match form statuses THEN search for link status `Other` and print it's link.

Can't come up with another approach. Just adding one more link_default object to a form doesn't sound too good for me.

Comment: in django template no such construction, but maybe you can try [jinja2-templates-django](http://jonathanchu.is/posts/upgrading-jinja2-templates-django-18-with-admin/)

Comment: @BearBrown how many stuff are absent in jinja2 engine? Already found out that it's django engine in here by default. Will filters be available for jinja2..? Don't want to ruin half of a project in here. Splitting by folders is not an option too..

Comment: i think for your case simple solution is create list in the view, as you need.

Comment: I don't see how this would help. I still need to save a state either loop found a match or not to use it later. In Django engine I can't use conditional loops, I can't set variables, and I can't use break, so how can I save variable if match was found? Because if wasn't then I could output default link. Now there's no way to detect if match was found.

Comment: Probably writing custom template tag is the only option in here